# Supplying an appliance with multiple power supplies

Tags: power-supply

Can I supply a single appliance using multiple power supplies?

For example if an appliance requires 100 watts of electricity, can I supply it with two power supplies, both of 50 watts?

Comment: How do you propose to connect two power supplies to one appliance? It *could* work, given two identical supplies with specific characteristics, but not with two arbitrary supplies.

Answer (score 2):

100 Watt is not electricity but Power.

The answer to your question:

in theory yes

in practice some voltage/current conversion might be needed. It also depends on what devices you're using. How will you make sure equal power is drawn from both supplies ?